# how to separate two varying arguments in a function when calling it

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
def family(*members,**Bills):
    contri=0
    for bill in Bills:
        print(bill)
        contri=contri+int(bill)
        pass
    contri=contri/len(members)
    return random.choice(members) ,contri
member,amt=family([['ayush','sankrt','amol'],[785,456,452])
print(member,amt)
```

Comment: `**Bills` being passed in kwargs form, it gets only arguments of the type `key=value`. You're passing _no_ arguments of that type here. For that matter, you aren't even doing anything that would call for `*args`, so why not just accept regular positional arguments for both?

Comment: (That is to say: For the code you have here, it would make more sense to just `def family(members, bills):`, and `member, amt = family(['ayush', 'sankrt', 'amol'], [786, 456, 452])`); there's no use case presented for `*args` or `**kwargs` at all).